# Publishing dacpac to Azure SQL Managed Instance from on prem SQL Server 2016 via PowerShell failing "cannot publish to SQL Server 2014"

Tags: azure, powershell, t-sql, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm trying to publish a dacpac extracted from a SQL Server 2016 on prem server to an Azure SQL Managed Instance using the below PowerShell, but this fails to the error below.

```
SqlPackage.exe /SourceFile:$DacPacFilePathName /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:$DatabaseServer /TargetDatabaseName:$DatabaseName /TargetUser:$User /TargetPassword:$Password

    SqlPackage.exe : *** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
    At line:9 char:1
    + SqlPackage.exe /SourceFile:$DacPacFilePathName /Action:Publish /Targe ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** An error oc...annot continue.:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform cannot be published to SQL Server 2014.
```

If I create a new DB in the Azure Managed Instance and create a dacpac from that, I'm able to use the same PowerShell command to publish it and it works fine.

Any ideas what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

The $env:Path on our deployment server was set to use SQLDB\DAC\140\SqlPackage.exe but SQL Managed Instance will only work with SQLDB\DAC\150\SqlPackage.exe

Answer (score 0):

The error was already trying to explain the issue

> A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform
> cannot be published to SQL Server 2014.

So [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-change-target-platform-and-publish-a-database-project?view=sql-server-ver15) you can find the Microsoft page for the target change when using DataPacs.